# Using a Razor function to set an Id

Tags: razor

I want to set a button id based on a DataRow value, and the value might have some special characters, so I have a function,

```
string ConvertNameToId( DataRow _row )
{
    return Regex.Replace( _row[ "SpecificColumnName" ].ToString( )
        , "[^A-Z0-9a-z]", "_" );
}
```

Then, in my tag, I have

```
id="@ConvertNameToId( row )"
```

This works, giving me `id="WHAT_EVER"`, but when I use if-then logic when building my tags, if I have multiple references to this function, I get a warning that "Another object on this page already uses ID '@ConvertNameToId( row )'.  Like this:

```
if ( boolValue )
{
    <td><button id="@ConvertNameToId( row )">...</button></td>
}
else
{
    <td><button id="@ConvertNameToId( row )">...</button></td>
}
```

I tried having the function supply the quote via string.Format, so that I could use `id=@ConvertNameToId( row )` without the quotes, but then I got `id=&quot;WHAT_EVER&quot;`.

I'm not suggesting that assigning id's this way is a good idea.  I'm just asking how to get the quotes in the html without the warnings or their being converted to `&quot;`.  As it is, my code is working; I'm just thinking that it could be done a better way to avoid the warning.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to fit in the Razor expressions some Razor comments and make each individual one different.

A Razor comment looks like this: `@* id1 *@`

This could make your warnings go away.

Or, a trick you cam make is to have a 2nd **unused** parameter to your function, say an `int` and give it as well dummy values to make the ID's look different.

```
<td><button id="@ConvertNameToId( row, 1 )">...</button></td>
<td><button id="@ConvertNameToId( row, 2 )">...</button></td>
```